# Few Q's on solenoids

Tags: solenoid

Sorry, this is not what I usually work with, so I'm kinda n00b on this..pardon my lack of knowledge and understanding. We have been having several issues with a few rather big solenoid on an industrial washer. They operate the locking bolt for the tumbler, and also function as an emergency stop.

1. Can solenoids be running on AC power? If so, how? (This has nothing to do with the actual solenoid — purely out of curiosity.)
2. Can any type of DC solenoid be reversed? The rod is held back by the solenoid as the machine operates, and returns by a spring. We have been having trouble with this spring cracking several times, and wondered if it would be possible to use the solenoid both ways?
3. What is the best material for the moving part of the solenoid? The better the electric leading capability, the greater the force will be? Or..?

A gentleman I spoke to said a possible reason for the spring cracking could be heat indued due to the magnetic field from the solenoid. And using a different type of material for the moving rod would help this.. But will this change the power of the solenoid? Or will it help anything at all?

4. Not-moving-parts mounted on or close to the solenoid.. FX a ballbearing or mountingbrackets. This will eventually get heated by the magnetic field? Will the use of non-magnetic material fix this?

Comment: The preferred format for SE is one question per question.

Comment: also, it's the **only** format that makes sense. An answer to your first question might make all the other questions obsolete, for example.

Comment: Heat would not cause the spring to crack. If anything, it would help anneal the spring and prevent cracking -- but also weaken it. It's much more likely that vibration from the machine as it operates is causing fatigue in the spring while it is under compression by the solenoid. In other words, you need to find a different spring, not a different solenoid.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Can solenoids be running on AC power?

Yes.

> If so, how?

Feed AC to the coil. Obviously, this causes a pulsating force, so many solenoids designed specifically for AC have "shaded" poles, which cause a phase shift in a portion of the magnetic field, reducing the vibration.

> 2. Can any type of DC solenoid be reversed?

Depends on what you mean by "reversed". You can reverse the current, but this doesn't accomplish what you're probably thinking.

> 3. What is the best material for the moving part of the solenoid?

Any ferromagnetic material. Iron is the cheapest and most readily available.

> The better the electric leading capability, the greater the force will be?

I have no idea what you're talking about here.

> Or..?

Or here.

> 4. Not-moving-parts mounted on or close to the solenoid.. FX a ballbearing or mountingbrackets. This will eventually get heated by the magnetic field?

No, not normally. The field external to the solenoid is usually quite weak.

> Will the use of non-magnetic material fix this?

Nothing to fix.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I usually work with, so I'm kinda n00b on this..pardon my lack of knowlege and understanding;p We have been having several issues with a few rather big solenoid on an industrial washer. They operate the lockingbolt for the tumbler, and also function as an emergencystop.

Q1: Had nothing to do with the actual solenoid, was purley out of curiosity.

Comment: Q2: The rod is held back by the solenoid as the machine operates, and returns by a spring. We have been having trouble with this spring cracking several times, and wondered if it would be possible to use the solenoid both ways? But that would not be possible as I understand you answer?

Comment: Q3 & 4: A gentleman I spoke to said a possible reason for the spring cracking could be heat indused due to the magnetic field from the solenoid. And using a different type of material for the moving rod would help this.. But will this change the power of the solenoid? Or will it help anything at all?

Comment: It sounds like the "gentleman" also has little experience in this area. But all of this additional information should be edited into the question, not given in comments.